# Standalone Linux Samba Server Authenticated by AD LDAP Backend?

Tags: ubuntu, samba, ldap

I'm trying to get a Standalone Samba server (non-domain joined) to authenticate via a Windows AD DS LDAP. I think the [documentation](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_%26_LDAP) is not quite right here, as I cannot get it to work that way.

I have extended the configuration of the docs a bit after it failed initially, but Samba still fails to startup:

```
[2021/04/23 16:02:59.404293,  0] ../../source3/smbd/server.c:1775(main)
  smbd version 4.11.6-Ubuntu started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2019
[2021/04/23 16:02:59.410542,  1] ../../source3/profile/profile_dummy.c:30(set_profile_level)
  INFO: Profiling support unavailable in this build.
[2021/04/23 16:02:59.435968,  1] ../../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:235(add_new_domain_info)
  add_new_domain_info: failed to add domain dn= sambaDomainName=RV-HR,DC=RV-Ing,DC=loc with: No such attribute
        00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090E48, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v2580
[2021/04/23 16:02:59.436031,  0] ../../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:313(smbldap_search_domain_info)
  smbldap_search_domain_info: Adding domain info for RV-HR failed with NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
[2021/04/23 16:02:59.436059,  0] ../../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap.c:6752(pdb_ldapsam_init_common)
  pdb_init_ldapsam: WARNING: Could not get domain info, nor add one to the domain. We cannot work reliably without it.
[2021/04/23 16:02:59.436075,  0] ../../source3/passdb/pdb_interface.c:179(make_pdb_method_name)
  pdb backend ldapsam:ldap://192.168.10.42 did not correctly init (error was NT_STATUS_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO)
```

The current `smb.conf` looks like this:

```
[global]
   #workgroup = RV-ING.loc

   server string = RV-HR
   netbios name = RV-HR
   realm = RV-ING.loc

   security = user
   passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://192.168.10.42
   ldap suffix = DC=RV-Ing,DC=loc
   ldap admin dn = CN=adquery,OU=service,DC=RV-ING,DC=loc
   ldap user suffix = OU=Mitarbeiter,OU=RV
   ldap group suffix = OU=Gruppen,OU=RV
   ldap machine suffix = OU=Computer,OU=RV
   ldap passwd sync = no
   ldap delete dn = no
   ldap ssl      = no
   ldap debug level = 4

   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   log level = 1 auth_audit:2
   log level = 1 auth_audit:3@/var/log/samba/samba_auth_audit.log
   max log size = 1000

   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

   server role = standalone server
   unix password sync = no

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

[Testshare]
    path = /media/GF
    directory mask = 0775
    public = yes
    writable = yes
    comment = HR Share
    printable = no
    guest ok = yes
    browseable = yes
    vfs object = full_audit
    force user = nobody
    force group = nogroup
    # server signing = mandatory
```

I have also considered maybe using PAM instead to get LDAP authentication to work, but arguably don't know enough about it. Any idea on how to get SAMBA to work with LDAP authentication?

Comment: Is there a strong reason for not wanting AD authentication but instead rolling your own through LDAP?

Comment: It's a Docker container; so each time it's recreated a new domain join would be required, creating a new AD computer object.

Comment: Ah! That would do it, wouldn't it

Comment: I really just want to authenticate each requesting user successfully. When using `map to guest` newer Windows OS will refuse to connect due to security concerns. I tried working around this by using local authentication and `user map script` to dynamically map any requesting user to a local service account. However a similar script-way doesn't exist for the password checking – if the the password of `smbpasswd` could be changed dynamically, that could already work; but haven't found any pointers on where to grab it during auth.

Comment: Another option I tried was using  PAM – adding `obey pam restrictions` to `smb.conf` and editing the `/etc/pam.d/samba` to consist of `pam_exec` all returning `exit 0` (returning success for the PAM step), but couldn't really get a foot in the door with debugging, as changing the statements seemed to have no effect and an `echo Auth > /tmp/t` I added to the scripts didn't execute either.

Comment: Please check that none of your configuration lines in `smb.conf` or any other relevant LDAP configuration files have [trailing spaces](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/a56b24c8-5929-46f6-8efe-757b450edc9c/error-when-trying-to-add-a-user-entry-to-active-directory-via-ldap-interface?forum=winserverDS).

Comment: Good idea! The configuration seems to be fine though. The main offender could have been `netbios name` since it's used as the computer name to add to the domain. `ldap.conf` is default. I experimented around a bit more – when the credentials are not right or if there's a whitespace behind the `admin dn`, the AD LDAP server rejects the request entirely.